# AttributeError: module object has no attribute '_name_'

Tags: python-2.7

Code I'm trying to run:

```
import humansize
humansize._name_
```

I get a '*name*' attribute error instead of 'humansize'.

I also get '*doc*' attribute error if I try:

```
import humansize
humansize._doc_
```

[enter link description here](https://github.com/pcsforeducation/diveintopython3/blob/master/examples/humansize.py)

Comment: Go back to whatever source you were reading and count the underscores again.

Comment: its two underscore not a single underscore `humansize.__name__` and simalarly `humansize.__doc__` for `name` and `docstring`